# CreationDate of a file is changing according to the context

Tags: c#, file-io

I am running some basic unit test on the creation date of files and I runned in a strange case (to me at least):

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        if (File.Exists(UncFile))
            File.Delete(UncFile);
        if (File.Exists(LocalFile))
            File.Delete(LocalFile);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ProxyFile_DeleteOlderFileOnLocalSystem()
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(LocalFile)) { }
        Thread.Sleep(50);

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(UncFile)) { }
        Thread.Sleep(50);

        DateTime UncDate = File.GetCreationTime(UncFile);
        DateTime OldLocalDate = File.GetCreationTime(LocalFile);

        Assert.IsTrue(UncDate > OldLocalDate);
    }
```

Works fine! whereas :

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(UncFile)) { }

        if (File.Exists(UncFile))
            File.Delete(UncFile);
        if (File.Exists(LocalFile))
            File.Delete(LocalFile);
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void ProxyFile_DeleteOlderFileOnLocalSystem()
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(LocalFile)) { }
        Thread.Sleep(50);

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(UncFile)) { }
        Thread.Sleep(50);

        DateTime UncDate = File.GetCreationTime(UncFile);
        DateTime OldLocalDate = File.GetCreationTime(LocalFile);

        Assert.IsTrue(UncDate > OldLocalDate);
    }
```

gaves me false... The Only Difference between the two being :

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(UncFile)) { }
```

But I delete this file just after :

```
if (File.Exists(UncFile))
                File.Delete(UncFile);
```

Could someone point me out what I am not doing right?

thx.

[EDIT]

the date in the second example seems to be like the first file UNC Created :

```
Debug.Print("UncFile : " + File.GetCreationTime(UncFile).Ticks);
->
UncFile   (Init) : 634632802355468953
UncFile   (Test) : 634632802355468953
LocalFile (Test) : 634632802355618962
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: It seems like if the creation time of the first UncFile is the same as the creation time of the second UncFile, maybe UncFile is not being deleted in Initialize()?

Comment: Try to debug your test step by step and look at the files while doing this and I'm sure you'll figure out what's going on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows filesystem: Creation time of a file doesn't change when while is deleted and created again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804342/windows-filesystem-creation-time-of-a-file-doesnt-change-when-while-is-deleted)

Comment: the files are correctly deleted, I have debugged it. The problem is to update the native functions responsible to give the Creation date. trying with 
   FileInfo fiUnc = new FileInfo(UncFile);
   fiUnc.Refresh();
   DateTime UncDate = fiUnc.CreationTime;
But does not work so far..

Comment: @Raymond exactly.. thanks fot the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found it :

> [File.GetCreationTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime.aspx)
>
> > Note This method may return an inaccurate value, because it uses
> >     native functions whose values may not be continuously updated by the
> >     operating system.

Thanks to raymond link's to another answer in Stackoverflow , Here is the solution :

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(LocalFile)) { }
            File.SetCreationTime(LocalFile,DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(50);

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(UncFile)) { }
            File.SetCreationTime(UncFile, DateTime.Now);
            Thread.Sleep(50);

            DateTime UncDate = File.GetCreationTime(UncFile);
            DateTime OldLocalDate = File.GetCreationTime(LocalFile);

            Assert.IsTrue(UncDate > OldLocalDate);
```

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say something along these lines. If you delete a file and create a new one of the same name very quickly it will retain some of the attributes from the old one I believe (it used to at least). I'm not sure if its just a case of not being updated by the system as it is a deliberate feature... I'd certainly be interested to see if you did that with an old already existing file whether the new file retains the old creation date or if it does eventually update... Looks like +Raymond Chen already covered this in a comment above. And better. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and providing a solution. Well done.