# why replacing a file doesn't renew its creation time?

Tags: windows, file, replace, timestamp

I use windows system. I have two files in two directory. One with creation time `2015/5/15 15:35`, the other with creation time `2015/5/15 9:48`. After I replace the second one with the first one, the modified time of the two files are the same, but **why the creation time of the second file doesn't change and is still `2015/5/15 9:48`?!**

Comment: How did you "replace" the file?

Comment: @Thilo just drag and release or ctrl+C and Ctrl+V

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804342/windows-filesystem-creation-time-of-a-file-doesnt-change-when-while-is-deleted

Comment: @Thilo So to renew the creation time, first I have to delete and then paste?

Comment: That links suggests that even if you delete and then paste, you will still get the "old" creation time. It's a feature :-)

Comment: @Thilo But I tried, it is renewed