# File.GetCreationTime() is returning strange value

Tags: c#, file

I am attempting to get the creation date of a file. I am using the [File.GetCreationTime() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this. If the file is a new file, it seems to work fine. If I delete the file though and re-create it, it seems to be giving me the original creation time. Since the file was deleted, it seems weird and even impossible that it is returning the original date and time of the file.

I put together a simple console application to demonstrate the issue:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string fileName = @"C:\Temp\dummy.txt";

    File.AppendAllText(fileName, "This is a test");
    DateTime creationDate = File.GetCreationTime(fileName);

    Console.WriteLine(creationDate.ToShortDateString() + " " + creationDate.ToShortTimeString());

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(120000);
    File.Delete(fileName);

    File.AppendAllText(fileName, "This is a test");
    creationDate = File.GetCreationTime(fileName);

    Console.WriteLine(creationDate.ToShortDateString() + " " + creationDate.ToShortTimeString());

}
```

This program creates a dummy file and appends the text `This is a test`. It then prints out the creation date and time to the console screen. So far, so good. It then sleeps for 2 minutes. After the 2 minutes have elapsed, it deletes the file and re-creates it. It then, again, prints out the creation date and time to the console screen. I would except the latter output to be 2 minutes later than the original, however, it is pulling the same exact date and time! I have single stepped through the program and I can verify that it is, indeed, deleting the original file from the hard drive.

```
Actual Output
--------------
5/6/2017 10:25 AM
5/6/2017 10:25 AM


Expected Output
----------------
5/6/2017 10:25 AM
5/6/2017 10:27 AM
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on here and how to work around the issue?

Comment: probably because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804342/windows-filesystem-creation-time-of-a-file-doesnt-change-when-while-is-deleted

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx) page

NTFS-formatted drives may cache information about a file, such as file creation time, for a short period of time. As a result, it may be necessary to explicitly set the creation time of a file **if you are overwriting or replacing an existing file.**