Is there something that caches deleted files for a period of time on the drive?
I am having problems determining the creation time of a file.
When I copy a file from one folder to another and delete the original file, the copy gets a new created date. If I copy the copy back to the original path, the new copy, which is now back in the original path, gets the old creation date from before the deletion.
Example:

File1  creation date 15.05.2022 13:12 (path: C:\Desktop)
File1  copied to File2 path (C:\Desktop\Test)
File2  creation date and creation time: 15/07/2024 10:59
File1  deleted from C:\Desktop
File2  copied from C:\Desktop\Test to C:\Desktop
File2  now has creation data again 15.05.2022 13:12

Windows specs:

Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version: 22H2
Installed at: ‎31.‎03.‎2021
OS-Build: 19045.4651
Pack: Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19060.1000.0

I guess something is stored in the cache.
How can I stop this behaviour?
I was expecting the file to get a new creation date because it has been deleted.

It's not exactly the cache of files, but yes, the filesystem does keep the information about the deleted files for some time (about 15 seconds). The purpose is to restore the old creation date when a file gets overwritten - this is exactly what you are experiencing. Here's an explanation with links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8810634/47961

Thank you very much! That is what i was searching for!
