# Ghost file remains alive when deleted and recreated

Tags: c#, file, delete-file

I just noticed a strange behavior with deleting and re-writing a file : the file creation time does not get updated if the interval is short enough between the two operations.

I ran the following code :

```
File.Delete("hello");
using(var stream = new StreamWriter("hello"))
{
    stream.WriteLine("hello");
}
var f = new FileInfo("hello");
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}ms", f.CreationTime, f.CreationTime.Millisecond);
```

If I put a breakpoint on the `using(...)` line, I can see the file disappearing after the delete, but at the end it will still give me the old creation date. I can even delete the file manually from the explorer and then run this code, it still shows the old creation time.

However, if I wait an undetermined time (around 1 minute) between the deletion and recreation, the creation time is set correctly (works if I wait with the debugger on the breakpoint mentioned above).

Where does this come from ? Is it a documented windows behavior ? Am I forgetting something ?

PS : I'm testing this on windows XP, for what it matters.

Comment: Consider either creating your FileInfo instance, then creating the stream from it, or closing the stream before creating the FileInfo instance.  If you look at the file system directly (with DIR in a shell or with Windows Explorer, you'll probably find the expected creation time).

Comment: @OllieJones `}` at the end of the using block closes the stream. And I didn't mention it, but I can see this creation time problem in the explorer property window as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem/feature in Windows called file tunneling.

Ref:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172190

Related:
https://serverfault.com/questions/92757/incorrect-file-creation-date-in-windows-xp-vista
[Why Windows sets new created file's "created time" property to old time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661977/why-windows-sets-new-created-files-created-time-property-to-old-time)
[Windows filesystem: Creation time of a file doesn't change when while is deleted and created again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804342/windows-filesystem-creation-time-of-a-file-doesnt-change-when-while-is-deleted)

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the refresh of your FileInfo (because data are cached):

```
var f = new FileInfo("hello");
f.Refresh(); // Force to read all props again
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}ms", f.CreationTime, f.CreationTime.Millisecond);
```

Comment: Same behavior. I guess this would have been useful is I was getting the `FileInfo` before creating the stream, but here it does nothing.